# Updating table with changes to textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table of vehicle info (5 fields per vehicle) with the capabilities of multiple vehicles per person.  I have all 5 fields and all vehicles going into a multidimensional array and populating a textbox based on the vehicle number (ie vic1, vic2...).  I need to update the table if any of the vehicle information is change. I have a different text box for each vehicle.  I'm not sure how to take the changes (additions/deletions/updates) and load it back into the table.

```vb
Private Sub cmdDone_Click()
  strMake1 = VicArray(0, 0)
  strModel1 = VicArray(0, 1)
  strYear1 = VicArray(0, 2)
  strColor1 = VicArray(0, 1)
  strPlate1 = VicArray(0, 1)

  strMake2 = VicArray(1, 0)
  strModel2 = VicArray(1, 1)
  strYear2 = VicArray(1, 2)
  strColor2 = VicArray(1, 3)
  strPlate2 = VicArray(1, 4)
.
.
.
  strMake6 = VicArray(5, 0)
  strModel6 = VicArray(5, 1)
  strYear6 = VicArray(5, 2)
  strColor6 = VicArray(5, 3)
  strPlate6 = VicArray(5, 4)

strUpdate = "Update VehicleInfo SET " & _
"Vic1License = '" & strPlate1 & "',Vic1Make = '" & strMake1 & "', Vic1Model = '" & strModel1 & "', Vic1Year = '" & strYear1 & "', Vic1Color = '" & strColor1 & " Handicapped= " & strhandicap & "'," & _
"Vic2License = '" & strPlate2 & "',Vic2Make = '" & strMake2 & "', Vic2Model = '" & strModel2 & "', Vic2Year = '" & strYear2 & "', Vic2Color = '" & strColor2 & "'," & _
"Vic3License = '" & strPlate3 & "',Vic3Make = '" & strMake3 & "', Vic3Model = '" & strModel3 & "', Vic3Year = '" & strYear3 & "', Vic3Color = '" & strColor3 & "'," & _
"Vic4License = '" & strPlate4 & "',Vic4Make = '" & strMake4 & "', Vic4Model = '" & strModel4 & "', Vic4Year = '" & strYear4 & "', Vic4Color = '" & strColor4 & "'," & _
"Vic5License = '" & strPlate5 & "',Vic5Make = '" & strMake5 & "', Vic5Model = '" & strModel5 & "', Vic5Year = '" & strYear5 & "', Vic5Color = '" & strColor5 & "'," & _
"Vic6License = '" & strPlate6 & "',Vic6Make = '" & strMake6 & "', Vic6Model = '" & strModel6 & "', Vic6Year = '" & strYear6 & "', Vic6Color = '" & strColor6 & "'," & _
" WHERE ( LastName= '" & TxtLast & "', AND FirstName= '" & txtFirst & "')"

DoCmd.RunSQL strUpdate
```

Comment: That approach can work, but it's a lot more work than what you could do. First, what is the problem you're having with that code? What's the error? Second, why aren't you using a bound form rather than VBA code to move the data?

Comment: No error, trying to figure out how to pass the concatenated fields  ` Me.txtVic1 = (VicArray(0, 0) & ", " & VicArray(0, 1) & ", " & VicArray(0, 2) & ", " & _
                VicArray(0, 3) & ", " & VicArray(0, 4))`  back into the database when the information is changed.  My experience with Access is very limited.  This code doesn't grab the changes.

Comment: Are you only wanting to update when there are changes? Either way, consider using a bound form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually split it by a delimiting variable and loaded it into a different array.

```vb
SplitArray1 = Split(txtVic1.Value, ",")
strMake1 = SplitArray1(0)
strModel1 = SplitArray1(1)
strYear1 = SplitArray1(2)
strColor1 = SplitArray1(3)
strPlate1 = SplitArray1(4)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do manually what Access can do for you automatically.

I would suggest setting the recordsource of your form to the table VehicleInfo. Then, set the control source of each control to the fields of that table.

Try this article, it should give you a good intro to using Access more effectively.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-forms-e8d47343-c937-44e8-a80f-b6a83a1fa3ae

I'm thinking you should have your VehicleInfo form filtered for the name chosen from the first form. The first form could have something like this:

```
public sub btn_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "VehicleInfoForm", , , "Name = '" & selectedName & "'"
end sub
```

And then the vehicle info form would display the information for that user. Whenever they make changes to the text boxes, it would be saved when they close the form. Assuming it is all bound properly.

Comment: I am trying to bind the box to the database, but I need to compare the user with input from another form. I call the name into a local text box but when I compare the table to the name text box I get a #Name? error.

Comment: So the user's input needs to be compared to another record? How are you retrieving that info? I think the syntax is [FormName]![FieldName]

Comment: I have the user select the name on one form (called from a demographics table) and load the name into my vehicle change form text boxes. I used the OpenArgs command to call the name.  I need to compare the name in the text boxes to the name in the vehicle ownership table.

Comment: Here is what I have sending the user name     `Public Sub cmdVic_Click()
strLast = cboLastName
strFirst = txtFirstName
'DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="EditVehicle", OpenArgs:=cboLastName & "|" & txtFirstName
`  The combobox is loaded from the Row source in the form properites.  `SELECT [EmployeeDemographics].[LastName], [EmployeeDemographics].[FirstName] FROM EmployeeDemographics ORDER BY [LastName], [FirstName]; `

Comment: I tried using the code and the data didn't load in the form.  I have the text box bound to the vehicle table,

Comment: What is the EditVehicle form's recordsource? It should be the VehicleInfo table (SELECT * FROM VehicleInfo), which you can then filter for the First and Last name of the user after they click the cmdVic button, instead of using OpenArgs. OpenArgs could work as well, but to me, direct filtering is easier.

Comment: I have that with a WHERE clause for first and last name on the form load and it will populate all the appropriate text boxes with the current vehicle information.  Now I need to figure out how to pull it from the text boxes after the vehicle has been modified in said text boxes and put it back into the database

Comment: If you want to do it this way, then you need to read the text boxes back into the VicArray. Your original posted code is fine, but you need to refresh the VicArray with the values from the text boxes.